# Computational cost of typedef

Tags: c

Is there any computational cost to using typedef?  I would assume so, since it's not a preprocessor instruction, but it very much seems like it would be something that would be used during compilation rather than at run time.

Comment: typedef is used at compilation time. So there is a less than negligible effect on your compilation speed, but no effect at run time.

Comment: @PaulDraper Thanks.  Is there a reason that it is not consider a preprocessor statement, or am I mistaken about this?

Comment: @John Gann Pre-processor statements are handled by the preprocessor, and is language independent -- "typedef" is a part of the C-language.   The preprocessor can be run over any file, wther c code or something else.

Comment: @JohnGann: because the preprocessor just does "stupid" text replacement, while `typedef` "knows" about types & co., all stuff which is handled by the compiler.

Comment: Preprocessing happens *before* compilation. Macros happens before compilation. This happens at compilation.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the preprocessor is *part of* the compiler. Some compilers invoke a separate program to do preprocessing; others do not. The C standard defines 8 "translation phases", and a compiler must operate *as if* there were implemented as separate phases. A typical preprocessor (if it's separate) corresponds roughly to phases 1 through 4.

Comment: And a `typedef` is nothing more than an *alias* for an existing type; it doesn't define a new type.

Answer (score 3):

Typedefs are just compiler declarations -- it does not actually make a difference to the generated code.